# Pulling a property up to the parent object level

Tags: nhibernate, join, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Take the following NHibernate scenario:

I have two tables:

```
Header
  HeaderID    (int),
  ForeignKey1 (int),
  ForeignKey2 (int)

Child
  ForeignKey1 (int),
  ForeignKey2 (int)
  Description (varchar)
  ...
  Metric Shed Ton Of Other Columns That Im Not InterestedIn(various types)
```

I'm using Fluent NHibernate - I'd like to project the value of `Description` on the `Child` object into the parent (is that the correct terminology?!) - but obviously `Child` contains a lot of data in its columns - I don't want all that extra data, just the description...how do I get NH to produce the equivalent of the following query:

```
select 
    Header.*, Child.Description 
from 
    Header 
inner join 
    Child ON Header.ForeignKey1 = Child.ForeignKey1 AND Header.ForeignKey2 = Child.ForeignKey2
```

The only way I've got this working up to now is to use a `Reference` mapping to reference the child from the `Header` entity and then just created a non-mapped property on `Header` which pointed to  `Child.Description`. Obviously this means that NH fetches the whole child object before it can query the value of `Description`

(I don't think the composite key is a problem here, the join seems to work fine - it's just how to get the data without getting all the non-interesting data)

At the moment my header entity looks like this:

```
public virtual int HeaderID { get; set; }
public virtual int KeyColumn1 { get; set; }
public virtual int KeyColumn2 { get; set; }
public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
public virtual string Description { get { return Child.Description; } }
```

The mappings for it:

```
  Id(x => x.HeaderID);
  Map(x => x.KeyColumn1);
  Map(x => x.KeyColumn2);
  References<Child>(x => x.Child).Fetch.Join().Columns("KeyColumn1", "KeyColumn2").ReadOnly();
```

Basically, I can't change the schema, I'm not interested in the rest of the data in the `Child` table, and I can't create views (can't change schema)

Anyone have any ideas if this is possible? I'm going to be querying a big list of `Header` objects, and I need that field from `Child` but I don't want the query to take forever!

Is this something I would have to do at the query level instead using hql or crit API?

Edit:

Trying to get this working using query API

```
Header.Session.QueryOver<Header>(() => parent)
            .Where(h => h.HeaderID == 1)
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Child, () => child)
            .Select(x => x.HeaderID, x => x.ForeignKey1, x => x.ForeignKey2, x => child.Description);
```

Checking the SQL shows the query is exactly what I want - but I get an exception `System.Object[] is not of type Header and cannot be used in this generic collection`

I assume this is because what I'm getting is just an array of values from the `Select()` - any idea how I can transform this into a `Header` object?

Edit: I ended up with

```
Header.Session.QueryOver<Header>(() => parent)
            .Where(h => h.HeaderID == 1)
            .Inner.JoinQueryOver(x => x.Child, () => child)
            .Select(x => x.HeaderID, x => x.ForeignKey1, x => x.ForeignKey2, x => child.Description)
            .TransformUsing(new GenericResultTransformer(typeof(Header), "HeaderID", "ForeignKey1", "ForeignKey2", "Description"));
```

Which works just how I want it - if anyone has a better suggestion I'm open to it, but like I said, I can't touch the schema at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the concept of lazy properties, but that is really for the opposite situation, i.e. there is a small number of properties that you want to exclude.

If this is for a presentation scenario, use can use any of NHibernate's query methods, to project just the columns you like - the query result need not be a complete entity. See for instance the select clause in HQL and LINQ, and the SetProjection() family in Criteria/QueryOver.

Comment: Thanks for this - I managed to get so far but I'm just trying to figure out how to get the returned results into my `Header` object - I'm hitting an exception (I've edited the question to show the details) - obviously though I want them in the `Header` object, not just a presentation of the values

Comment: It smells like a design problem - if you so much need the Description in the Header, why isn't it there to begin with?

Comment: Or to put it another way: The idea with NHibernate is to follow an object oriented design. Typically a class is expected to have a single responsibility, but unless you always need the Description in Header, it sounds like you may be trying to use it for multiple different purposes.

Comment: Basically it's an existing (microsoft) application - I've just managed to get this working with a `ResultTransformer`. I can't change the schema, I don't want to place items such as views in the database as they may be dropped when the database goes through an upgrade etc. I also want to ensure I don't need to deploy anything to the database, NH abstracts the database as a model so it's ideal for what I want. The description is against a "one" table and the header is the "many" table and I want to ensure my business objects contain the description. I don't see a problem with that...

Comment: I still can't quite work out what you mean by `follow an object oriented design` - are you saying that for every query that gets a list of `Header` objects, I should also be getting a whole `Child` object? Or that I shouldn't relate the two? The two **are** related - `Header` references `Child` so why can't header summarise one of the child's properties? How would you have this working? I'm using two frameworks that don't see eye to eye that well so I'm using my NH entities as DTOs (lazy loading is done via the other framework - it's SL so it's async lazy loads)

Comment: I've accepted since you helped me get there, but if you have any better suggestions as to how to get this working (without touching the schema) then please let me know :)

Comment: Object oriented => has both behaviour and data. (Except for things like DTOs of course.) Single responsibility principle, etc. But sometimes when there are outer constraint like you mention, one may need to be pragmatic, and have a design that isn't quite optimal from a theoretical view point. But you don't except to ever update the Description from Header's property? Perhaps it can also be done by mapping Header.Description using a formula... except that would probably lead to a correlated subquery (=bad performance). Given your circumstances, perhaps you've done what can be done.

Comment: Thanks for this, yes the description is meant to be read only (I didn't mention this in the question, maybe I should have) - technically it's for display purposes but from a framework point of view it needed to be part of the DTO - thanks for your insight anyway!